# XSL - Insert div after n-th element

Tags: xslt

I want to insert `<div class="test"></div>` after n-th element on every page:

now:

```
<iaixsl:for-each select="/shop/page/products/product">
  <div class="product col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 pt-3 pb-md-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0 ">
  ...
  </div>
</iaixsl:for-each>
```

and now I want to put

```
<div class="banner">
...
</div>
```

after 3rd product element.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<xsl:if test="not(position() mod 3)">
    <!-- your addition goes here -->
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use XSLT 2 or 3 you could also use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/shop/page/products/product" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 3">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()">
    <div class="product ...">..</div>
  </xsl:for-each> 
  <div class="banner">..</div>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```